# CREATE PROCEDURE: mysql syntax error

Tags: mysql, procedure

I always get a syntax error when I `DELCARE @qty INT`, as I `SET qty = ...` and `AND q = @qty`

I don't know how to correct those syntax error!

Here the procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE test(target INT)
BEGIN

    DECLARE qty INT

    -- Get closest qty
    @qty = SELECT q
            FROM MH
            ORDER BY ABS(@target - q) ASC
            LIMIT 1


    -- use that "actual" qty in your query
    SELECT  ((p+m)*((valore+100)/100))
    FROM    PL
    JOIN    TV
    JOIN    MH
    WHERE   Date = '20130717'
    AND     End = ''
    AND     q = @qty

END
```

Comment: and the syntax error is...? perhaps it's the lack of `;` terminating your two queries, making the DB think that the second select is actually part of the first query's `LIMIT`?

Comment: @MarcB: `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@qty = SELECT q' at line 7`

Comment: because you forgot the `;` after the declare line as well...

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE test(target INT)
BEGIN

DECLARE qty INT default 0;

SELECT q into qty
        FROM MH
        ORDER BY ABS(target - q) ASC
        Limit 1;
SELECT  ((p+m)*((valore+100)/100))
FROM    PL
JOIN    TV
JOIN    MH
WHERE   Date = '2013/07/17'
AND     End = ''
AND     q = qty;

END
```

Comment: I get this error: `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 4`

Comment: Try to remove all @ symbols.

Comment: There are any `@` symbol at line 4... I did it, it doesn't work

Comment: Please put a backquote before and after date, end column names. Similarly if you are trying to run this in phpmyadmin then ad delimiter // in the top and end your stored procedure with //